# Read folder, parse filenames and call other program

Tags: applescript, automator

In brief, I need to do something like this:

1. I have a folder with a lot of files and want to process all files with extension .epub.
2. All files already follow a naming scheme: Lastname, Firstname - Title.epub or Lastname, Firstname - Series x - Title.epub and I need a parser for Lastname, Firstname, Series (if existing) and Title.
3. I have a command-line tool that sets metadata: ebook-meta filename -a "Firstname Lastname" -t Title

There are many snipplets for 1.), however I am in need for input for 2.) and appreciate any help/pointers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can start with the following and change it to meet your needs. It compiles, although untested.

```
set p to POSIX file "/Users/kaass/Desktop/test/"
tell application "Finder" to set filelist to name of every file of folder p

repeat with filename in filelist
    set text item delimiters to ""
    if text -5 thru -1 of filename is equal to ".epub" then
        set temp to items 1 thru -6 of filename as text

        set text item delimiters to " - "
        set myWord to text items 1 thru -1 of temp
        set title to myWord's last item as text

        if myWord's length is equal to 3 then set series to myWord's second item as text

        set myWord to item 1 of myWord as text
        if myWord contains "," then
            set text item delimiters to ", "
        else
            set text item delimiters to " "
        end if
        set author to (text item 2 of myWord) & space & (text item 1 of myWord)
        set path_and_filename to POSIX path of file p & filename
        do shell script "echo Processing file " & quoted form of path_and_filename & ": " & author & " +++ " & title
        do shell script "/Applications/calibre.app/Contents/MacOS/ebook-meta " & quoted form of path_and_filename & " -a " & quoted form of author & " -t " & quoted form of title
    end if
end repeat
```

Just comment if you need something to be changed.

Comment: Thanks, this is great. It needed some changes to get this running: First, the if "if text -5 thru -1 of a is equal to ".epub" then" and second, I had to save and restore the original delimiters (at the beginning and the end of the if), otherwise it only works for the first item in the list: "set oldDelimiters to my text item delimiters" and "set my text item delimiters to oldDelimiters". Finally, I have an additional question: How can I make the "Lastname, Firstname" fail-safe, if there is just a name such as "National Geographic" without a ","?

Comment: Works like a charm except the call of the ebook-meta. It seem to be a problem with encoding/escaping. I did some google research and added quoted form and if I change the line to "do shell script "echo /Applications/calibre.app/Contents/MacOS/ebook-meta \"" & quoted form of filename & "\" -a \"" & quoted form of author & "\" -t \"" & quoted form of title & "\""" I get the output "/Applications/calibre.app/Contents/MacOS/ebook-meta 'Adler-Olsen, Jussi - Carl Mørck 1 - Erbarmen.mobi' -a 'Jussi Adler-Olsen' -t 'Carl Mørck 1 - Erbarmen'". If I paste this to command line, it is executed correctly.

Comment: Without the echo and directly executed by the script, "No such file or directory: u"'Adler-Olsen, Jussi - Carl M\xf8rck 1 - Erbarmen.mobi'"

Comment: So it now works with your changes ? Or else I can do better escaping for the do shell script line.

Comment: No, it does not work, see my last two comments. I think, it's a problem with encoding acutally, see the Mørck vs. M\xf8rck. It's not the original question anymore, however, if you have another idea, I would be thankful :)

Comment: perhaps try adding `as unicode text`. ie `set fname to text item 2 of myWord as unicode text`

Comment: The problem seems to be somewhat simpler, here is a demo: <code> set p to POSIX file "/Users/markus/test"

tell application "Finder" to set filelist to name of every file of folder p

repeat with filename in filelist
 set quotedfilename to quoted form of filename
 do shell script "echo " & quotedfilename
 do shell script "ls -la " & quotedfilename
end repeat </code>  Now just put one file into this directory named "Haas, Wolf - Ausgebremst.mobi", it seems to be that the string passed to ls is not quoted...

Comment: `quoted form of` always does the correct thing. It shouldn't be the problem. I changed the do shell script line in the above answer. It might be better.

Comment: No, this is not the problem...I tried this. Besides, your line could not work anyway, correct it has to be "do shell script "ebook-meta " & filename & " -a " & quoted form of author & " -t " & quoted form of title" with another change "repeat with filename in filelist". I extracted the problem into the second test script in my comment before this one. If you copy this, you'll see that it is the filename itself...

Comment: If I run the code you gave me, it works fine. The `ls` does not work because you are trying to list a file not because it's incorrectly quoted. As you see the argument for the ls is correctly quoted with single quotes. http://db.tt/5PY2aUAr

Comment: Unfortunately, this is not correct. My screen looks exactly like your screenshot (except .mobi instead .epub). However, if you copy/paste this into your Terminal, ls is executed correctly: "ls -la 'Haas, Wolf - Ausgebremst.mobi'
-rw-r--r--  1 markus  staff  284716 30 Nov 22:10 Haas, Wolf - Ausgebremst.mobi".....that means, ls has to list it, what happens seems to be that ls only get's part of the string, cut off somewhere.

Comment: The problem is that the current working directory is not the same. If you look at the following screenshot it shows the current working directory as `/` whilst the file is in the `/test/` directory. http://dl.dropbox.com/u/24907/screen2.png

Comment: That's it...thank you very much for your help. I accept your answer, however, you should update the do shell script in your answer to "set author to fname & space & lname
  set path_and_filename to POSIX path of file p & filename
  
  do shell script "echo Processing file " & quoted form of path_and_filename & ": " & author & " +++ " & title
  do shell script "/Applications/calibre.app/Contents/MacOS/ebook-meta " & quoted form of path_and_filename & " -a " & quoted form of author & " -t " & quoted form of title
"